# Undesired shape in svg appearing via zoom

Tags: html, svg

I made a svg from html, and for the most part, it works - save for an issue where the "last segment" of the svg has a part that protrudes out, in a weird shape it's not supposed to be. It only seems to happen every "other" zoom level, e.g. 75% bad shape appears, 100% it doesn't, and 110% it does again, and so forth.

I've spent hours on trying to understand the problem, but all that I've gotten to knowing is that the "last segment" is the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
    <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="3"></circle>
  
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#ce4b99" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="5.111524164  94.88847584" stroke-dashoffset="50"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="3.531598513  96.46840149" stroke-dashoffset="144.8884758"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#377bbc" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="2.695167286  97.30483271" stroke-dashoffset="141.3568773"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="2.695167286  97.30483271" stroke-dashoffset="138.66171"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#ce4b99" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="1.858736059  98.14126394" stroke-dashoffset="135.9665428"></circle>

    
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="1.858736059  98.14126394" stroke-dashoffset="134.1078067"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="1.672862454  98.32713755" stroke-dashoffset="132.2490706"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="1.486988848  98.51301115" stroke-dashoffset="130.5762082"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="1.486988848  98.51301115" stroke-dashoffset="129.0892193"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="1.394052045  98.60594796" stroke-dashoffset="127.6022305"></circle>
    
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="1.301115242  98.69888476" stroke-dashoffset="126.2081784"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="1.208178439  98.79182156" stroke-dashoffset="124.9070632"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="1.115241636  98.88475836" stroke-dashoffset="123.6988848"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="1.022304833  98.97769517" stroke-dashoffset="122.5836431"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="1.022304833  98.97769517" stroke-dashoffset="121.5613383"></circle>

    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="1.022304833  98.97769517" stroke-dashoffset="120.5390335"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="1.022304833  98.97769517" stroke-dashoffset="119.5167286"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.92936803   99.07063197" stroke-dashoffset="118.4944238"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.92936803   99.07063197" stroke-dashoffset="117.5650558"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.92936803   99.07063197" stroke-dashoffset="116.6356877"></circle>
 
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.92936803   99.07063197" stroke-dashoffset="115.7063197"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.836431227  99.16356877" stroke-dashoffset="114.7769517"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.836431227  99.16356877" stroke-dashoffset="113.9405204"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.836431227  99.16356877" stroke-dashoffset="113.1040892"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.743494424  99.25650558" stroke-dashoffset="112.267658"></circle>
     
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.743494424  99.25650558" stroke-dashoffset="111.5241636"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.650557621  99.34944238" stroke-dashoffset="110.7806691"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.650557621  99.34944238" stroke-dashoffset="110.1301115"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.650557621  99.34944238" stroke-dashoffset="109.4795539"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.557620818  99.44237918" stroke-dashoffset="108.8289963"></circle>

    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.557620818  99.44237918" stroke-dashoffset="108.2713755"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.557620818  99.44237918" stroke-dashoffset="107.7137546"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.557620818  99.44237918" stroke-dashoffset="107.1561338"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.557620818  99.44237918" stroke-dashoffset="106.598513"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.557620818  99.44237918" stroke-dashoffset="106.0408922"></circle>
       
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.464684015  99.53531599" stroke-dashoffset="105.4832714"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.464684015  99.53531599" stroke-dashoffset="105.0185874"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.371747212  99.62825279" stroke-dashoffset="104.5539033"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.371747212  99.62825279" stroke-dashoffset="104.1821561"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.371747212  99.62825279" stroke-dashoffset="103.8104089"></circle>

    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.371747212  99.62825279" stroke-dashoffset="103.4386617"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.278810409  99.72118959" stroke-dashoffset="103.0669145"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.278810409  99.72118959" stroke-dashoffset="102.7881041"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.278810409  99.72118959" stroke-dashoffset="102.5092937"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.278810409  99.72118959" stroke-dashoffset="102.2304833"></circle>
    
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.278810409  99.72118959" stroke-dashoffset="101.9516729"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.278810409  99.72118959" stroke-dashoffset="101.6728625"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.278810409  99.72118959" stroke-dashoffset="101.394052"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.278810409  99.72118959" stroke-dashoffset="101.1152416"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.185873606  99.81412639" stroke-dashoffset="100.8364312"></circle>
    
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.185873606  99.81412639" stroke-dashoffset="100.6505576"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.092936803  99.9070632" stroke-dashoffset="100.464684"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.092936803  99.9070632" stroke-dashoffset="100.3717472"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.092936803  99.9070632" stroke-dashoffset="100.2788104"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.092936803  99.9070632" stroke-dashoffset="100.1858736"></circle>
    
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="0.092936803  99.9070632" stroke-dashoffset="100.0929368"></circle>
  </svg>
```

This is the "issue" that I'm seeing, visually.
[image: Image-donut-error]

Comment: Probably a bug with the stroke-dasharay. I can see it in Chrome but not in FF (Safari doesn't render anything) If you lower the precision of the stroke-dasharrays to 4 digits after the dot it works fine in Chrome (`0.0929 99.9071`) but Safari needs it to be `0.2, 99.8`, which makes it not very precise... The best is probably to use <path> elements here rather than tricks with the dash-offset.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you! It's a problem I'd probably never have found out, as I'd looked in the direction, but not far enough. That seems to have solved it for chrome at least - just unfortunate that Safari doesn't do a great job.

Comment: It's the last circle that is giving you the problem. Please try to replace it with a path: `<path stroke="red" stroke-width="3" d="M36.91549430918954,21A15.91549430918954,15.91549430918954 0 0 1 5.0845056908104596,21A15.91549430918954,15.91549430918954 0 0 1 36.91549430918954,21" stroke-dasharray="0.092936803  99.9070632" stroke-dashoffset="100.0929368" fill="none"/>`